# CommonJS vs JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, commonjs

I need to add comments to my JSON without using another NPM package, so I had the idea to add `module.exports =` to the start of my JSON file so that it becomes a CommonJS module (with a normal JS Object) that I can use in the exact same way. Are there any trade-offs I need to know when doing this?

Comment: Then it’s not JSON and can’t be used in the “exact same way”. Does it work in the specific case? Apparently it does (?), with the trade off of it being a JavaScript module and not JSON.

Comment: You're just turning your JSON file into a module file.  If a module is what you want, then it will work fine.  If JSON is what you want, then a module is not going to work as someone trying to load and parse your file as JSON will get an error.

Comment: By exact same way, I meant that the way to import it is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this:

```
const data = require('myfile.json');
```

with JSON data in the file:

```
{"someProp": "someValue"}
```

Or, you can do this:

```
const data = require('mfile.js');
```

with this in the file:

```
module.exports = {"someProp": "someValue"};
```

One is a module file.  One is a JSON file.  It really just depends upon what you want it to be or if there are any other clients of this file that expect it to be one way or the other.  There are no specific advantages or disadvantages either way, though the CommonJS module can contain more types of data, comments, etc... because JSON is very restrictive about what could be in there.  Both will work just fine for the core data if you follow the appropriate format rules.

If you want to add Javascript comments to the data, then you cannot do that in JSON so you will need to make it a module and there's no specific drawback to doing that.

Note, for `require()` to automatically parse the JSON, it has to have a `.json` file extension.  For it to be parsed as a Javascript CommonJS module, it must not have a `.json` file extension.

Comment: @ma1234 - If loading/parsing time was critical to you, you would have to benchmark your specific situation and measure it.  It would be two completely different loading/parsing mechanisms.